# Jquery random hover on images, images popup but some doesn't restore back to their original size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 9 images arranged in 3 rows. Each row has 3 images. All the images are of different size. On hover I am increasing the image width and height to 400px and 300px respectively and on mouseout I am restoring back to their original size. Now the problem is when I hover randomly, images popup but some doesn't get back to their original size. How do I fix this? Please help.

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        jQuery('my-selector').hover(function() { 
var someVariable = jQuery( 'my-selector img', this );
someVariable.attr('actualWidth', someVariable.width()); 
someVariable.attr('actualHeight', someVariable.height());
jQuery('my-selector').stop()
              .animate({
                width: "400px",             
                height: "300px"
            }, 200, function() {
                // Animation complete.
                jQuery('show-some-div').show();
            });
        },  
 function() {  
jQuery('my-selector').stop()
              .animate({
                width: someVariable.attr('actualWidth'),                
                height: someVariable.attr('actualHeight')}, 200, function() {
                // Animation complete.
                jQuery('show-some-div').hide();
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually three potential problems here that I spot.

**The first** is that you're sort of vaguely reselecting your elements when an event fires. This means that even though only one of your images is firing, you're doing various things to all of them, or else having to do some gymnastics in order to get back to what the user actually interacted with.

What can help you with this problem is the fact that within a jQuery event callback, the contextual reference variable `this` will point at the html element that the event refers to. This means that instead of doing

```
var someVariable = jQuery('my-selector img', this);
```

you can do

```
var someVariable = jQuery(this);
```

and it'll be a jQuery object that points at the html element that fired the event. I like to keep to a convention where jQuery objects start with a $, so I usually do something like

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Regardless, now that you definitely have a reference to the element that actually caused the `mouseover` or `mouseout` event, you can use it to do your actions (I'll stick with someVariable for now):

```
someVariable.stop().animate({ ... });
```

The **second problem** is that you're kind of mucking with the DOM when you start `attr`ing random attributes onto HTML elements. `actualWidth` isn't a real HTML attribute, and some browsers will take more kindly to that fact than others. Thankfully, jQuery provides a way to store off variables that are related to some particular HTML element. Simply use `.data` rather than `.attr` exactly the way you're already using `.attr`, and it'll store away the data you want:

```
someVariable.data('actualWidth', someVariable.width()); // sets actualWidth
// ... some time later ....
var someOtherVariable = someVariable.data('actualWidth'); // gets actualWidth
```

The **third problem** I see here is: what happens if someone mouses out of your element, but before it's returned to its natural size, they mouse back on? Now you're measuring the image before it's shrunk back down to its `actualSize`, and calling that its `actualSize`. To solve this, simply measure their `actualSize`s as each one loads (you don't want to do `page load` because the images might not yet be loaded, you want to do the `load` event for each image, and each image will fire its `load` event when it is loaded and sized):

```
jQuery('my-selector img').load(function()
{
    var someVariable = jQuery(this);
    someVariable.data('actualWidth', someVariable.width());
    someVariable.data('actualHeight', someVariable.height());
});
```

Now that you've measured each image and stored off what is truly its proper size, you don't have to do the work each time on `mouseover`; simply expand the image to 400x300 on `mouseover` without caring, and then back to the stored off `actualWidth` and `actualHeight` when they mouseout.

Between those three issues, your problem should be nailed.

Comment: or perhaps use queue false at the end of .animate could be neat? Or?

Comment: +1, great answer. I would as well check if `actualWidth` and `actualHeight` is set before doing any resizing on hover.

Comment: Excellent analysis Clint. I will try all these things and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Clint , it really helped me a lot in finding out where the problem is . I found something called hoverIntent (a plugin) . Now what it does is , it popups an image only if you hover for 1 or 2 seconds. So even if i randomly hover on images none of the images popup.. This solves my problem